# Can't access to Azure Storage folder using Lucene.Net

Tags: azure, azure-storage, lucene.net

We decided to implement a search functionality in our API which is developed in ServiceStack, we decided to use Lucene.Net since we heard it was a great indexer to make searches.

We created a worker role whose job is to create the indexes in a Azure Storage folder, we guided ourselves using [Leon Cullen's tutorial](http://leoncullens.nl/post/2012/11/18/Full-Text-Search-on-Azure-with-LuceneNET.aspx). We use the [AzureDirectory library](https://github.com/azure-contrib/AzureDirectory) specified in that post, so we could use the latest Azure SDK.

Then in our API project we added the references for Lucene.Net and AzureDirectory too, our endpoint ended up looking like this:

```
    public object Post(SearchIndex request)
    {           

        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

        var pageSize = -1;
        var totalpages = -1;
        int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PageSize"], out pageSize);

        if (request.Page.Equals(0))
        { 
            request.Page = 1;
        }

        // Get Azure settings
        AzureDirectory azureDirectory ;

        try
        {
            // This is the line where we get the Access denied exception thrown at us
            azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringAzureSearch"]), "indexsearch"); 

            IndexSearcher searcher;
            using (new AutoStopWatch("Creating searcher"))
            {
                searcher = new IndexSearcher(azureDirectory);
            }

            using (new AutoStopWatch(string.Format("Search for {0}", request.SearchString)))
            {
                string[] searchfields = new string[] { "Id", "Name", "Description" };

                var hits = searcher.Search(QueryMaker(request.SearchString, searchfields), request.Page * pageSize);

                int count = hits.ScoreDocs.Count();
                float temp_totalpages = 0;
                temp_totalpages = (float)hits.ScoreDocs.Count() / (float)pageSize;

                if (temp_totalpages > (int)temp_totalpages)
                {
                    totalpages = (int)temp_totalpages + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    totalpages = (int)temp_totalpages;
                }

                foreach (ScoreDoc match in hits.ScoreDocs)
                {
                    Document doc = searcher.Doc(match.Doc);

                    int producId = int.Parse(doc.Get("Id"));

                    Product product = Db.Select<Product>("Id={0}", producId).FirstOrDefault();

                    products.Add(product);
                }

            }

            return new SearchIndexResult { result = products.Skip((int)((request.Page - 1) * 10)).Take(pageSize).ToList(), PageSize = pageSize, TotalPages = totalpages };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return new HttpResult(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "azureDirectory. Parameter: " + request.SearchString + ". e: " + e.Message);
        }



    }
```

If we run this locally it works as expected, returning us the results we were expecting. But when we published our API to Azure and tried to access to the search endpoint we received an 403 error message with the message 'Access to the path "D:/AzureDirectory" is denied".

We're confused as to why is trying to access to such folder at all, the name of the folder is wrong and I think it's trying to access a local route, we really don't know why does it work fine locally but once it's deployed to Azure it stops working.

The worker role runs without a problems, but it's the API side that cannot access to the folder in Azure Storage. Are we missing some important step in the configuration? The tutorial we followed wasn't very clear for beginners using Lucene.Net or Azure Storage so we fear we might have missed an important step. We've checked our connection strings and everything seems ok though.

Comment: Did you come to any conclusions? Im having the similar sort of problems. I can create the index in my cloud service and I can read from it as expected when I run my web api locally but when I run it in a azure website it throws up. The thing is it used to work so Im suspecting it has to do with some updates.

Answer (score 1):

As for reference:
https://github.com/azure-contrib/AzureDirectory/blob/master/AzureDirectory/AzureDirectory.cs

when you do this

```
azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringAzureSearch"]), "indexsearch");
```

This executes

```
var cachePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory), "AzureDirectory");
var azureDir = new DirectoryInfo(cachePath);
if (!azureDir.Exists)
    azureDir.Create();

var catalogPath = Path.Combine(cachePath, _containerName);
var catalogDir = new DirectoryInfo(catalogPath);
if (!catalogDir.Exists)
    catalogDir.Create();

_cacheDirectory = FSDirectory.Open(catalogPath);
```

So simple solution for you might be to have that directory on site root

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/"));
azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(storageAccount, containerName, new SimpleFSDirectory(info), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.

- I just got the latest version of AzureDirectory from GitHub.
- Got the latest nuGet packages for Azure Storage etc.
- Recreated the index.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@brykneval answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41902618/1657465), I tried his solution but last parameter `bool compressBlob = false` which he set to `true` made my local debug fail with 404 exception from AzureDirectory library and when I published to Azure web app, it had exception with message: `System.IO.InvalidDataException: Block length does not match with its complement`.

I removed last parameter from constructor and everything works like a charm. Hope this helps anyone.